# "can't access property "getAuthInstance", gapi.auth2 is undefined" error while trying to use YouTube data API

Tags: javascript, api

so I'm kinda new to API and stuffs like this. Recently I've got a task to list videos from a specific Youtube channel. So the workaround I got is to first collect the id of `uploads` playlist, then get all videos from that playlist to show them. But the thing is I couldn't go so far, I first got the code from Googles API documentation, did some edits (my api key and stuff like this) and when I run I get this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: can't access property "getAuthInstance", gapi.auth2 is undefined

here's the code i'm using (i'll delete my API Key, so don't think its the error):

```html
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"></script>
  <script>
    /**
     * Sample JavaScript code for youtube.channels.list
     * See instructions for running APIs Explorer code samples locally:
     * https://developers.google.com/explorer-help/guides/code_samples#javascript
     */

    function authenticate() {
      return gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance()
        .signIn({
          scope: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly"
        })
        .then(function() {
            console.log("Sign-in successful");
          },
          function(err) {
            console.error("Error signing in", err);
          });
    }

    function loadClient() {
      gapi.client.setApiKey("my API key was here");
      return gapi.client.load("https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/youtube/v3/rest")
        .then(function() {
            console.log("GAPI client loaded for API");
          },
          function(err) {
            console.error("Error loading GAPI client for API", err);
          });
    }
    // Make sure the client is loaded and sign-in is complete before calling this method.
    function execute() {
      return gapi.client.youtube.channels.list({
          "part": [
            "contentDetails"
          ],
          "id": [
            "My Channel ID was here"
          ]
        })
        .then(function(response) {
            // Handle the results here (response.result has the parsed body).
            console.log("Response", response);
          },
          function(err) {
            console.error("Execute error", err);
          });
    }
    /*gapi.load("client:auth2", function() {
      gapi.auth2.init({
        client_id: "YOUR_CLIENT_ID"
      });
    });*/
  </script>
  <button onclick="authenticate().then(loadClient)">authorize and load</button>
  <button onclick="execute()">execute</button>
```

from the looks of the error it seea ms to me that there's problem with api.js library or maybe there supposed to be another function I need to execute before calling `getAuthInstance`. I don't have any idea what is happening so hopefully someone can explain to me what is happening, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about this stuff myself so I went to the docs and found this section for you:
https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/reference#gapiauth2getauthinstance

Turns out you need to initialise auth first - the bit you've commented out at the bottom of your code:

```
/*gapi.load("client:auth2", function() {
  gapi.auth2.init({
    client_id: "YOUR_CLIENT_ID"
  });
});*/
```

Give that a test and see what you get :D

Comment: okay so I've commented it out because in the doc I saw you either need a api key or a client id, so since I already have a api key I thought that's what causing the problem so I commented it out, I'll look for initializing it with a api key

Comment: the problem is for getting a client id I need to submit a long ass form